# Confusion with primary key

Tags: sql, database, database-design, primary-key

I am new to designing database. Maybe its a stupid question so please pardon me for that. So the thing is I am designing the database for users. After user fills registration information he gets the unique receipt number. So my question is since receipt no. is unique can I use it as a primary key in Users table or should I stick with standard method of assigning userID to each row in table and use userID as primary key?

Comment: What are these receipts?

Comment: Is the user *identified* through his receipt number? As in: Will he keep this number until the end of times and will this number never be used for any purpose other than identifying this user? If yes, go ahead. If no, use a separate userID that fulfills these requirements.

Comment: its like when user fills the info, unique receipt number is sent to user's email. and using that receipt number he can view status of his order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your receipt no. is complicated enough - built using numbers and characters, or 20 digits in length - better use the surrogate UserId

If receipt No can be simple integer and may be generated from DB - better use UserId and assign its value to ReceiptNo

If ReceiptNo is simple integer and its identifies the user **AND** the only user - use it as PKey.

Comment: Oleg Dog, thanks for the quick reply. I think it is better idea to use auto incremented user ids since the receipt number will be alphanumeric and of 8 characters.

Answer (score 2):

A table can have more than one key. If the receipt number is intended to be unique and you want the DBMS to enforce key dependencies on that attribute as a data integrity constraint then yes you should make it a key (with uniqueness implemented by a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint or whatever mechanisms your DBMS provides).

Designating any one key to be a "primary" one isn't especially important - or at least it is only as important as you want it to be. What really matters is the full set of key(s) you choose. The requirements for any key are Uniqueness and Irreducibility. Sensible criteria for choosing a key are also: Familiarity, Simplicity and Stability

Comment: And perhaps add that typically, surrogates score very close to zero on the familiarity criterion, and non-surrogates MIGHT score poorly on the stability criterion.

Answer (score 1):

if your receipt number contains only integer number then, may be you can make your receipt-no field as auto-increment number,

Comment: receipt number will be alphanumeric and may be of 8 characters.